# change the install prefix during installation in RPM

Tags: rpm, specifications, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have rpm1.rpm and rpm2.rpm. I want to install rpm2.rpm to the same place which rpm1.rpm were installed. rpm1 had been relocated when it was being installed. by the command below I take the relocated prefix

```
rpm -q --queryformat '%{INSTPREFIXES}\n' rpm1
```

now, what should I do in the spec file till rpm2 prefix change to the output of the above command even user doesn't relocate rpm2 to the path? in other words, I want to install rpm2 in the same place which rpm1 is installed.

Comment: I think you could add this to a `%pre` rule and RPM allows updating of variables.  However, it is kind of surprising to a user if you are giving this to third parties.  If you maintain the deployment system for the target (embedded device?) then maybe it is okay.  If it is a generic PC target, I think it would confuse people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prefix and reloctable rpm package according to an other rpm prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736277/prefix-and-reloctable-rpm-package-according-to-an-other-rpm-prefix)

Answer (score 0):

As @artless-noise suggested it is confusing for users and will not be supported by standards. probably you can hack it somehow but it is not recommended way to go.

there are following possible alternative, I could be more specific if you had mentioned the reason why you want same location.

- use **Conflicts** tag in spec file, if you don't want rpm1 on same system
- use **Obsoletes** tag in spec file, if you want to uninstall rpm1 before installing rpm2
- Use alternative package system, if you want to install both rpms at same time and want to allow system admin to select default between them.

for more please check https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Alternatives/